# c++ how do i add a double and a string making one string?

Tags: c++

I am currently just to create a string that includes a few things,

```
double num = 2.5;
string letter = "M";

string allTogether = num+letter
```

I'd like allTogether to look like this "2.5M", but to add the num to a string I thought i had to convert it to a string using to_string, but when you do that, the double converts like this, 2.5000000, how do I get the outcome i'm looking for? Thanks!

Comment: `std::ostringstream ss; ss << num << letter; std::string allTogether = ss.str();`

Comment: You should open your textbook to the chapter that explains how to use `std::ostringstream`, and follow the given examples. These basic fundamentals should be fully explained in every C++ textbook, and unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not really a replacement for a textbook.

Comment: Look up [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 0):

Make a stream object and set precision and then use it to convert your double.

```
std::ostringstream streamObj3;

// Set Fixed -Point Notation
streamObj3 << std::fixed;

// Set precision to 2 digits
streamObj3 << std::setprecision(2);

//Add double to stream
streamObj3 << num;
```

Comment: Missing the final part, get the string :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
double num = 2.5;
string letter = "M";

string allTogether = to_string(num).substr(0, 3) + letter;
```

**EDIT:** In order to get the first decimal after point, you can do the following

```
string num_str = to_string(num);
string allTogether = num_str.substr(0, num_str.find_first_of(".") + 2) + letter;
```

The second argument of `substr` is exclusive. Adding `2` here includes 1 character after `"."`.

Comment: Who voted to delete this answer? I need an explanation about why.

Comment: Most likely reason for the delete vote is whoever downvoted this answer wants the reputation they spent on the downvote back and is trying to hasten the deletion of the answer. Unlike the answer suggesting `sprintf`, this answer can be fixed and should be given the chance.

Comment: @Jarod42 Editted for all cases.